# Checking if a constant is empty

Tags: php

Why is this not possible?

```
if(!empty( _MY_CONST)){
  ...
```

But yet this is:

```
$my_const = _MY_CONST;
if(!empty($my_const)){
  ...
```

---

```
define( 'QUOTA_MSG' , '' ); // There is currently no message to show

$message = QUOTA_MSG;
if(!empty($message)){
  echo $message;
}
```

I just wanted to make it a little cleaner by just referencing the constant itself.

Comment: Doesn't empty expect a variable? (In the first call, it's receiving a constant.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the [manual](http://php.net/empty): `empty()` is a language construct, not a function.

> `empty()` only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`.

So you'll have to use a variable - `empty()` is really what you want in the first place? It would return true when the constant's value is "0" for example.

Maybe you need to test for the existence of the constant using `defined()` instead?

Comment: Thanks Pekka. So I have to keep the const assigned to the variable then, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the point of a constant is knowing the value is predictable - i.e. it being constant - so why would you even -need- to test for empty? I'm insanely curious. =)

Comment: @jim yup - if `empty()` is really what you want? It would return true when the constant's value is "0" for example. Maybe you want to test for the *existence* of the constant using `defined()` instead?

Comment: +1, quoting the manual, "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var", so you will get the expected result with `if(! _MY_CONST)`

Comment: Well, I'm assigning a string to the constant and then using it to show a message to the user. I wanted to test if the constant was empty then show no message. How would you handle that?

Comment: @Benjamin: `if (!!_MY_CONST)`

Comment: @jim, if you're replying to me, I was merely curious about the usage of a constant, and not a variable. Perhaps I'm just not used to the language paradigms of PHP. =)

Comment: Check whether the string is empty before you assign it to the constant?

Comment: @J, I was replying to Pekka. No worries. :)

Comment: @J. to answer your question about paradigms, the use of constants for this is not usual in PHP... We don't know the details of course, but there might well be a more elegant solution.

Comment: If I use `! MYCONST` I get null echoed to the screen.

Comment: @Pekka, it's just a message that I am echoing to the user about their quota has been reached.

Comment: Sure, gimme a sec and I'll post above

Comment: @jim but why use a constant if the message can be empty? That's  what I mean by "unusual"

Comment: Because the way I have this laid out, all of my messages are in a single file. I only want to go to one place to edit them. How would you do it?

Comment: @jim that's an okay approach up to a certain size of project, but why do you have to test the constants for emptiness then? Will they not always contain something unless there was an editing/translation error?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, currently, we have no quotas set, we are working on them so, in the mean time, the constant will have to remain empty until we finish it. It may be a couple of months and the system is live so we just want to suppress the messages for now.

Comment: @Pekka, Benjamin offered this: `if (!!_MY_CONST)`. I've never seen double `!!` before. WHat is this saying?

Comment: @jim ah, okay. If it's just about echoing, you wouldn't have to do the test though - `echo EMPTY_CONSTANT` will not output anything. Re the `!!`, the  first `!` will do a conversion to boolean (which follows the same rules as `empty()` does), the second one will invert the value. If the result is `true`, the constant is not empty

Comment: @Pekka, Inside the if statement, I have a database query that I want to protect if it's empty. The query gets info about the user that is stored in the database.

Comment: @Pekka, can you tell me what this is saying? `if (!!_MY_CONST)` I've never seen 2 `!!` before.

Comment: @jim I edited info abot the `!!` into my last comment. Re the if statement, it's too hard for me to tell what you're doing exactly, so I can't comment on whether what you're doing is good practice or not.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know, thanks for the explanation, Pekka. All I'm doing is protecting the database query from running if there is no message to show. It is pointless to run a query if there is no message to echo.

Comment: @nickf yes sorry, I meant to get the same result as empty()

Comment: @jim, `!!` does an implicit conversion to a boolean, the preferred way would actually be to convert it explicitly: `(bool) _MY_CONST`. If enclosed inside a `if()`, which expects itself a boolean, it's the same as doing a straight `if (_MY_CONST)`. But maybe you're looking for `defined()`, as pointed by Pekka?

Answer (score 13):

Just letting you know that you can do

```
if(!empty(MY_CONST))
```

since [PHP 5.5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.empty).

Answer (score 7):

You can get along with this if for some reason you are *still* not using PHP 5.5.

```
if (defined('MY_CONST') && MY_CONST) {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!empty(constant('MY_CONST')) {
    ...
}
```

> mixed constant ( string $name )
>
> Return the value of the constant indicated by $name, or NULL if the constant is not defined
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Answer (score 2):

what about strlen?

```
if(strlen(MY_CONST) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If constant defined and need check is empty or not, for example you use it in config file, you can use `!MY_CONST`:

```
define('MY_CONST', '');
if (!MY_CONST) {
    echo 'MY_CONST is empty';
}
```